# Have a sandbox account in PayPal with negative balance

Tags: paypal, sandbox, account

I am trying to have a sandbox account which I create with $1.00 with the balance, but as it has a credit card linked, bam, it just grabs more money from the credit card like nothing as I try for billing to fail precisely because I need to charge for outstanding balance which is what I'm testing.

So credit card linkage, always money even with an account of $0.00 balance, then bank linked and the same happens. The test account must be verified to make purchases on this which is recurring. Yet it should fail billing, I haven't gotten up to the next billing cycle which comes in a few hours (testing with daily as recurring) to see if one of initially $1.00 accounts for this $1.00 cycle will fail but that won't happen I guess because a credit card or bank account was linked to those test accounts.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to configure Negative Testing for your Sandbox accounts:

Page 45 here: https://www.x.com/sites/default/files/pp_sandbox_userguide.pdf

Then, pass in the error code desired as the Transaction Amount Field, for example 106.06 to invoke error code 10606 "Buyer cannot pay". The US site error codes are here: http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/PP_APIReference/Appx-ErrorCodes_and_Messages.html